# Pesquisa para usuários do SOpt em 2015

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

O SOen realiza uma pesquisa no final/começo de ano com os participantes do site para saber as preferências do pessoal sobre tecnologias usadas no dia a dia, horas trabalhadas, horas gastas no site etc. Com uma versão do SO em português, seria interessante conhecer as tecnologias usadas, um pouca realidade e ambiente de trabalho dos lusófonos.

Poderiamos ter essa pesquisa no SOpt em 2015?

A pesquisa faz parte do stackoverflow? ou seja está incluída no pacote de localização?

[Resultado da presquisa - 2013](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/)

[Resultado dos Anos anteriores](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/survey/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nada impede que organizemos nossa própria pesquisa aqui no Meta (não sei como, mas pode ser dado um jeito), e nada impede que os usuários do SOpt respondam a pesquisa "oficial".

Mas por enquanto não vamos ter a pesquisa oficial em Português.